# Correlation between mutual information and thermodynamic entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, information

Does a system having a lower thermodynamic entropy imply that there is greater mutual information between the variables associated with its constituent parts? I.e., in a lower entropy system, any one measurement a single component's value for variable X tells you more about variables Y and Z than in a higher entropy system. Example: the momentum of individual molocules of a gas are more closely related to each other's positions before you increase the entropy of the system by doing something like increasing the volume.

Thus, equilibrium = measurement of any one component's value for a variable gives minimal information about the other variables' values, minimum entropy = any measurement of a variable gives maximal information about the others?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of Shannon and Kolmogorov's theories, and various other formulations. This would be using Shannon's theory. The question would be: is the mutual information with the macrostate variables or other microstate variables?

Comment: @TimBrown   The term *"information between [the system's] constituent parts"* is vague. Mutual information connects two probability distributions. What distributions do you have in mind in the context of thermodynamics?

Comment: @Themis I see that now. I will make an edit. I meant everything you need to define the system's point in its phase space. Would mutual information potentially decrease with higher entropy for some but not all variables?